# get-aduser to make list of properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I dont understand why my code cant get this code to work. I am trying to do a get-aduser that lists the name, alias, and the homepage of all users in the active directory domain. Nowhere online explains what to use with `get-aduser` to get the extended properties of all the users in AD.  i am using this as my code:

```
Get-ADuser -filter * -properties extended | FT name, homepage, identity
```

what am i doing wrong? any hrelp would be greatly appreciated. 
For exporting to an excel sheet i use.

```
 PS P:\> Get-ADuser -filter * -properties name,HomePage,userprincipalname | FT name,homepage,userprincipalname | out-file C:\scripts\AD.csv
```

This creates a list of all the AD users but it puts them under one column like so:

[image]

I need to have each section under a seperate column

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say alias? there is wether a property called alias nor identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to list the properties you want, for example:

```
Get-ADuser -filter * -properties EmailAddress,HomePage
```

Here is the documentation: 
[Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx)

Regarding csv export:

```
Get-ADuser -filter * -properties name,HomePage,userprincipalname | select name,homepage,userprincipalname | export-csv C:\scripts\AD.csv -notype
```

should yield the expected result. If you need to change the delimiter you can use the `-delimiter` parameter.

Comment: When I try that it says a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*'

Comment: @TylerS I'm inclined to say that you copied something wrong since Pauls code should work.

Comment: i couldnt find the difference but copying and pasting justified the issue.

Comment: idk if you could help with this but the last part i am doing is exporting to a csv file. works great exports. however the info i have export puts each property under one column. I am trying to break it up so A is for Name, B is for Homepage, and C is for Userprincipalname